# OpenVPN and dhcp-option domain-route for Windows/Linux

Tags: linux, windows, domain-name-system, openvpn, dhcp-option

I am trying to understand the dhcp-options usage for Windows and Linux (Ubuntu).

There seems to be difference between the implementation.

Using OpenVPN 2.4 server and client, i test on Windows 10 21H2 and Ubuntu 20.04.
I have a domain `foo.bar`, which is a DNS server, followed by multiple subdomains `x.foo.bar`, which are with private IPs and not public DNS records.

The options that are of interest to me are:

`dhcp-option DOMAIN`
and
`dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE`

I first found some forum post, that if i want to route specific DNS requests for X domain only, i should use `DOMAIN-ROUTE`.

And so i did set a push option on the OpenVPN server.
On Ubuntu, using `resolvectl status`, i get the `DNS Domain: ~foo.bar`
Testing queries only for `x.foo.bar` returns expected results.
So it works.

But when i tried it under Windows i observed the following error:
`Options error: --dhcp-option: unknown option type 'DOMAIN-ROUTE' or missing or unknown parameter`

After searching for a bit, i was surprised, that i could not find any information about `DOMAIN-ROUTE`.

Looking at the IANA BOOTCP DHCP Parameters, i could not find such option there.

Then i went and used the `DOMAIN` option when testing for both Windows and Ubuntu.
This time, i could see it on Windows as well: `Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : foo.bar`
But DNS queries did not work, since it keeps trying to use the default DNS server, instead of the pushed one.

Question is:

what is `DOMAIN-ROUTE` and how it differs from `DOMAIN`?

Is there an dhcp-option, that would work the same way on Windows, as it does on Linux, in regards to querying a specific DNS server when the requested DNS matches a domain search list/suffix.